# How to add values to Double[] arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I created this arrayList:

```
Double[] arrayOfNumbers = new Double[List.size()];
```

And I try to add it numbers with this:

```
arrayOfNumbers.add(0.9);
```

This gives me an error message that says:

> Cannot invoke add(double) on the array type Double[]

So, how can I add that value in this `Double[]` arraylist?

Answer (score 3):

That is not an `ArrayList`. That is an array.

You can declare an arraylist of doubles as :

```
int initialCapacity = 20;
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>(initialCapacity);
doubles.add(0.9);
```

You can add more than `20` values in an `ArrayList` even though the initial capacity is specified as `20`.

But to declare an array and populate it:

```
double[] doublesArray = new doubles[20];

doubles[0] = 0.9;
doubles[1] = 0.5;
.....
doubles[19] = 0.7; // 19 is the last index for an array of size 20.
```

If you add more than `20` here, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: In your `ArrayList` example, I think you are confusing the array *size* with its *capacity*. There are definitely related, but aren't the same thing ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos I modified the word `size` to `initial capacity` to remove confusion.

Answer (score 2):

`Double[]` is not `ArrayList` to add to an array you can use :

```
Double[] arrayOfNumbers = new Double[List.size()];
arrayOfNumbers[0] = 0.9;
```

Instead to add to an `ArrayList` you can use :

```
List<Double> arrayOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
arrayOfNumbers.add(0.9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and lists are different things. Arrays don't have an `add` method, but are assignable by the subscript (`[]`) operator:

```
arrayOfNumbers[0] = 0.9;
```

Answer (score 1):

> `Double[] arrayOfNumbers = new Double[List.size()]` is not a List
>   it is an array.
>       We declare arrays with [] and lists with <> and generics. 
>       For example `

`int[]arr=new int[3]` is an array of 3 ints, but `List<Integer>list=new ArrayList<>()` is a list of integers(not primitive ints you CANNOTwrite code like this `List<int>=new ArrayList<>()`

> ```
> Hope that helps!
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.List` is a different that an `array`(which has limited `predefined` `size`).

you can't declare/perform as above you did in question, java compiler will complain if you do so.

you are phasing a error like,

> Cannot invoke add(double) on the array type Double[]

because an array(arrayOfNumbers) do not having a such method(add) which you can execute on `arrayOfNumbers`.

However,
general syntax to initialize of an array of any type(here in example, Integer taken FYI) is likewise,

```
int intArray[] = {1,2,3}; // initialize at the time of creation
or
int arrayOfNumbers [] = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
or
intArray[index] = 1;
```

Moreover, you can switch from `array` to `List` & vice-versa as likewise,

```
List<Integer> list = java.util.Arrays.asList(arrayOfNumbers);
```

or

```
Integer [] intArray = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `List` is an `Interface` that extends another interface called `Collection`, so a `List` is-a `Collection`. An `Interface` defines and describes behavior, it defines a contract that another class must conform to, and one of the classes that does so is called `java.util.ArrayList`, and `add()` is one behaviour defined in the `List` contract, because a List must have the ability for things to be added to it. An ArrayList is one type of a `List`. What you have created is NOT an ArrayList, it is an Array.

An array is a primitive data structure, once created, it's size cannot be changed, If you wish to add a new element to an array you have to create a new array that is bigger, then transfer all elements from the old array to the new one. Under the covers an `ArrayList` does exactly that. THIS IS HOW YOU CREATE an ArrayList :

```
//a list of Objects of type `Double`
List<Double> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

if you wish to add an element to this list, you would do this :

```
listOfNumbers.add(5.2);
```

You do seem like you still need to read a beginners book and practice basic Java programming. I would like to suggest this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WiPGP_0AUA&list=PL9DF6E4B45C36D411)

This will really be helpful to you, and remember you can only learn something by doing it hands-on, NOT by just watching somebody else doing it.